# Why can't I read a file by name from an ifstream if I redirect it via commandline to standard input?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am currently setting up VSCode to code with C++ on my new Linux laptop. Now i wanted to try Debugging with a text input file. However, getting the text file as argument to my program was much harder than i thought. I want the program to work as if i typed `./program.exe t2.txt` in the terminal.

I spent like the last 2 hours on researching how to do that in VSCode and figured out, that i must have something to do with the launch.json. Now i modified it in a way so at least an input argument is recognized(which took 2 hours)

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": ["1","<","${workspaceFolder}/t2.txt"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

ow at least my program recognizes , that it gets an argument as input, however i get the error that it isnt a file? Basically, this runtimeerror is thrown when i try to run the program

```cpp
std::ifstream file(filename);  // open file
if (not file) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open file.");
}
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is that based on recent experience? I'm experienced with both emacs and VS Code, and as much as I love emacs, I wouldn't recommend it to a new user, even on linux. TLDR; I've found the combination of CMake (with presets) and C++/CMake extensions to be productive (I have the opposite experience of make -- could never figure out the tabbing!). It's personal preference in my opinion; curious why you're so definitive.

Comment: What is the value of `filename`? Are you sure it is what you expect it to be (Look at it in the debugger (or print it)).

Comment: Based on recent experience on Stackoverflow, @TooTone, VSCode is overwhelming for newbies. Emacs works fine as a plain text editor. Either plain make, or CMake, has a small learning curve. As long as someone doesn't expect instant gratification, they can be easily absorbed without requiring extensive development background.

Answer (score 0):

You're "passing" the file to your program through the standard input stream by doing redirection (Ex. see [docs for Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Input))- not by passing the file name as a commandline argument to the program (where it would be available in `argv`).

Commandline arguments (`argv`) and the standard input stream (`std::cin`) are completely different things.

If you want to get the filename from `argv` and them open a file by that name, then don't use shell redirection (take out the `<`). If you want to use redirection, then read the file contents from `std::cin` (the standard input stream).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have trouble understanding your answer. So should i just put                                    ' "args": ["1","${workspaceFolder}/t2.txt"]," ' in the launch,json without the <? Because that doesnt work either, it gives me the same runtimeerror

Comment: @SteveMichael where is your `filename` variable from? I assumed `argv`. If that doesn't work, then more details is needed. see [mre].

Comment: yes it is from `argv`, but just taking out the "<" sadly doesnt work.

Comment: Now, after taking out the "<", if you take look at what `argv[1]` is, now, then it shouldn't be difficult to figure out the rest.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you mean `argv[2]`? Their arguments in launch.json start with `1`.

Comment: No, @starball, `argv[1]` which appears to set `filename`. Hopefully, after seeing what it is, and after staring at the arguments, how this works -- and what needs to be done -- will come about.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ? wouldn't the arguments without the `<` be [0]: <program name>, [1]: "1", [2]: <filename> ?

Comment: Correct, @starball, and by observing that, hopefully, it will become obvious how to fix the configuration setting. One always learns better when they figure it out themselves, instead of simply being told what to do.

Comment: I got it  , Thank you!